# How to Configure WSO2 DAS And WSO2 API Manager

Tags: wso2, analytics, wso2-api-manager, wso2-das

I need to Configure WSO2 DAS with my WSO2 API Manager to publish the API Runtime Statistics.

Regards.

Comment: You can follow https://docs.wso2.com/display/AM1100/Publishing+API+Runtime+Statistics+Using+RDBMS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two ways to do this

1. Publishing API Runtime Statistics Using RDBMS
2. Publishing API Runtime Statistics Using REST Client

Have a look on [Publishing API Runtime Statistics](https://docs.wso2.com/display/AM1100/Publishing+API+Runtime+Statistics)